# Arc<Struct> with fields as HashMap, cannot borrow as mutable, why?

Tags: rust

I'm using this struct:

```rust
pub struct Store {
  pub player: HashMap<i64, Player>,
  pub team: HashMap<i64, Team>,
}

impl Store {
  pub fn new() -> Arc<Self> {
    Arc::new(Self {
      player: HashMap::new(),
      team: HashMap::new(),
    })
  }
}
```

sharing it in my resolvers with:

```rust
async fn player_by_id(&self, store: Arc<Store>, id: i64) -> Result<()> {
  let team = get_team();

  store.team.insert(id, team.into()); // here I get the error
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Arc` as mutable
   |
84 |         store.team.insert(id, team.into());
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<Store>`
```

**Why?**

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0596

Comment: This does not help.

Answer (score 3):

[As explained in `Rc`'s documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/index.html),

> Shared references in Rust disallow mutation by default, and [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) is no exception: you cannot generally obtain a mutable reference to something inside an [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html).

`Arc` is the same as `Rc` in this regard. You need to use a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html)
(or [atomics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/index.html)) to change its contents.

Comment: So I should write from this:

```rust
pub struct Store {
  pub player: HashMap<i64, Player>,
  pub team: HashMap<i64, Team>,
}
```

to this:

```rust
pub struct Store {
  pub player: Mutex<HashMap<i64, Player>>,
  pub team: Mutex<HashMap<i64, Team>>,
}
```

?

Comment: @FredHors This is one option. Another is to use the [`dashmap`](https://docs.rs/dashmap) crate, that should be faster.

Comment: The usual pattern here is to slap a `RwLock` on it if you need to modify.